# Android CameraX Exif how to get latitude,longitude, time?

Tags: android, time, latitude-longitude, exif, android-camerax

Why I can't get pictureLatitude,pictureDateTime,pictureLatitude,pictureDateTime value?
They all null?
But I can get outputFileResults,byteArrayInputStream values.

> Log.d(TAG, "filePath: $filePath") print=>filePath:
> /external/images/media/1000000030 . But at my real mobile phone, the
> photo's path is  storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CameraX-Image.

## ====================================================================

==========================================

```
private fun takePhoto() {
        val imageCapture2 = imageCapture1 ?: return

        val name =
            SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.TAIWAN).format(System.currentTimeMillis())
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/CameraX-Image")
            }
        }

        val outputFileOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
            context?.contentResolver!!,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            contentValues
        ).build()

        imageCapture2.takePicture(
            outputFileOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: ${outputFileResults.savedUri}"
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, "onImageSaved: $msg")

                    val filePath = outputFileResults.savedUri?.path ?: return
                    Log.d(TAG, "filePath: $filePath")
                    

                    val originalUri =
                        MediaStore.setRequireOriginal(outputFileResults.savedUri!!)
                    Log.d(TAG, "originalUri: $originalUri")

                    val byteArrayInputStream =
                        outputFileResults.savedUri?.path?.byteInputStream() ?: return
                    Log.d(TAG, "byteArrayInputStream:$byteArrayInputStream ")
                    val exif = ExifInterface(byteArrayInputStream)
                    val pictureLatitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE)
                    val pictureDateTime = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME)
                    val latLong = exif.latLong
                    val altitude = exif.getAltitude(0.0)
                    Log.d(TAG, "pictureLatitude: $pictureLatitude")
                    Log.d(TAG, "pictureDateTime: $pictureDateTime")
                    Log.d(TAG, "latLong: $latLong")
                    Log.d(TAG, "altitude: $altitude")
                    println(pictureLatitude)

                }

                override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exception.message}", exception)
                }
            })
    }
```

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, "filePath: $filePath")` Please tell what this prints.

Comment: @blackapps Log.d(TAG, "filePath: $filePath") print=>filePath: /external/images/media/1000000030 . But at my real mobile phone, the photo's path is  storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CameraX-Image.

Comment: Can be. But you are using the first one for exif. A nonsense path. No wonder.

Comment: @blackapps So what should I do now?

Comment: outputFileResults.savedUri?.path?.byteInputStream() change to,: outputFileResults.savedUri?.byteInputStream()? So use the uri. Not a part/path of it

Comment: @blackapps outputFileResults.savedUri?.  with no byteInputStream() method.I use val inputStream = context?.contentResolver?.openInputStream(outputFileResults.savedUri) ?: return. val exif = ExifInterface(inputStream). But still exif.getAttribute() return null.

Comment: Please adapt your code above with it as i have a hard time understanding what you do..

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74118668/android-exifinterface-longitude-latitude-missing-after-android-10